# Debian Tor Node - Can't update to newer version

Tags: debian, apt, tor

I run a tor node on debian. Nyx says that my version (0.2.9.16 (git-9ef571339967c1e5)) is obsolete.

But when I try to do `apt update && apt upgrade`, nothing happens, all packages seem up to date. And `apt-cache showpkg tor` only shows my current version and older ones.

What am I doing wrong? Why can't I update tor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re doing nothing wrong. The fact that your system has version 0.2.9.16 [tells me that you’re running Debian 9](https://qa.debian.org/madison.php?package=tor), and Debian 9 only has version 0.2.9.16 of Tor. However, newer versions have been made available in [the backports repositories](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/), and you can install version 0.4.1.6 from there:

```
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
echo deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch-backports-sloppy main | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/stretch-backports.list
sudo apt update
sudo apt -t stretch-backports install tor
```